# How to retrieve certificate information of a .Net dll in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i want to retrieve certificate information e.g, "Issued to", "Issued by" values of a given .net dll programmatically.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it with something like:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("your_assembly.dll");
string exe = asm.Location;
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate executingCert =
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(exe); 
Console.WriteLine (executingCert.Issuer);
```